# How can i Integrate PayPal with ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

How can i integrate PayPal with ASP.NET, do you have any sites that can get me started or links to any tutorials?

Comment: Paypal has several integration options.  Which option are you wanting to use?  ie: Website Payments Pro, Website Payments Standard, Express Checkout, Payflow Pro,....

Answer (score 10):

Read paypal integration in asp.net from [Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/PayPalIntegration/PayPalIntegration.asp)

Update: There is [PayPal Helper](http://nuget.org/packages/PayPal.Helper) for web matrix that could be easily integrated to asp.net mvc or asp.net web forms.

Answer (score 8):

You'll have to use [Paypal IPN](https://www.paypal.com/ipn) for that. My site runs with Perl, but the way it basically works is as follows:

1. Customer fills out an order form at my site with their name, address, email.
2. Customer is being redirected to Paypal
3. Upon successful payment via Paypal, Paypal calls my IPN-compliant script
4. My script sends me an e-mail notifying me about the completed order

If the customer does not pay within 30 minutes or so, my database also sends him a reminder with a Paypal payment link for the respective order.

Answer (score 2):

Download the ASP.NET E-Commerce Start Kit, which is now "DashCommerce". It has PayPal implemented. http://dashcommerce.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can give this Paypal NVP API example in C# (asp.net) a try: http://brad.w3portals.com/2008/02/paypal-nvp-api-example-in-c-aspnet.html

Tries to give a simple example to get you up and running quick. The paypal SDK example are not that great. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Michael987 put together posts from different forums to come up with a [solution that worked well for him](http://forums.asp.net/t/1236969.aspx/1?Paypal+Encrypted+Website+Payments+EWP+Solution).

NathanRidley integrated the codes from the link above and released an [open source library on Github](https://github.com/axefrog/XMerchant)