# Paypal payment method asp.net

Tags: asp.net, paypal

Hello I have a E commerce website and I want to sell via paypal payment method but I've couldnt find a good source to follow for asp.net entity framework. Could you please lead me for this? if u guys have any source for it I would like to follow it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i Integrate PayPal with ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638114/how-can-i-integrate-paypal-with-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal offers SDKs written in .NET for both the [Payflow Gateway](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/#payflow-gateway) and the [Classic API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sdks/) platforms.

Comment: Thank You m8 gonna check these