# How paypal integration using wcf service?

Tags: paypal

Actually i want to create wcf service for paypal integration and will access this service in web application (.net) using jquery or mobile.  So all the paypal integration work should be in wcf service.

So do you have any idea about it. 
Please help to solve the query.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i Integrate PayPal with ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638114/how-can-i-integrate-paypal-with-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very specific, so here's my best shot: you create a standard WCF service whose implementation connects to the Paypal Web API. Both are documented really well so I suggest you follow articles such as these:

1. [End to end tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers)
2. [Paypal API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/)
3. [List item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

There could be easier or shorter ways but this will give you the most flexibility in the long run (and less headache in the short term).

Comment: Actually my requirement is user gives his credit card information with amount pay to my WCF service and that WCF Service deduct amount from user account and add  amount to website owner by integrate  paypal

Comment: Then I think you need to read my first link. The user only needs to provide his credit card information to PayPal and not to your application in plain text (in the best case that'll be over a secured wire). After the payment is done you'll get information about the result, which you can use to manage your user account in your application.

Comment: I have read all links which you mention above but i did not get any solution of my problem. i want user just pass his credit card information from my website and my website pass user credit card information to my WCF service then my WCF service call Pay  pall  credit card api and send result to my website is payment successfully or not.